# Laravel, Is there any way to sync whole table with array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There is an API call of client-server which returns Invoices approx 600 and it takes time upto 2,3 minutes because they didn't optimize.

So there is a condition that I need to filter the data with `paid: false`, I did that too.

After that, I'm storing record In my database to keep track of Invoices and adding comments and sending reminders.

[image: I have to save reminders and comments with current Model]

The problem is there's a case if Invoice becomes `Paid: true` then It will be neglected in the filter, So how I will update my table because it will remain false there.

```
    $response = collect(\GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()));
            $filtered = $response->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($now) {
                return ($value->paid == false && $value->dueDate <= $now);
            });
            $this->saveInvoices($filtered);
```

```
    public function saveInvoices($filtered)
        {
            foreach ($filtered as $val) {
                $item = collect($val);
                array_push($this->filteredResults, $item->only(['invoiceNumber', 'customerId', 'customerName', 'dueDate', 'invoiceDate', 'amountInOriginalCurrency', 'paid'])->toArray());
            }

            foreach ($this->filteredResults as $item) {

                UnpaidInvoices::updateOrCreate(
                    ['invoiceNumber' => $item['invoiceNumber']],
                    ['invoiceNumber' => $item['invoiceNumber'],
                        'customerId' => $item['customerId'],
                        'customerName' => $item['customerName'],
                        'dueDate' => $item['dueDate'],
                        'invoiceDate' => $item['invoiceDate'],
                        'amountInOriginalCurrency' => $item['amountInOriginalCurrency'],
                        'paid' => $item['paid']]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, be aware that checking due date against "now" moment is not safe. If for some reason your checks will pause (like network problem, API server maintanance etc), then your algorithm will fail.
Example: Today is Saturday and your script wasn't working yesterday, you checking invoice with dueDate = "Friday" it was paid at Friday also.
You will never know about paid status changed, because Friday already pasts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have indexes well set in DB.
2. Return only what you really need from a Back-End (no filtering on Front-End)
3. UPDATE on record change shall be a separate call after retrieving the collection/array, maybe easiest followed with another CALL to fetch latest results (point 1).

Answer (score 0):

You want to update information from all received invoices, but save the only not paid one to `$this->filteredResults`.
You can move your "filter logic" inside `$this->saveInvoices()` method and that will solve the issue.

```
$response = collect(\GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()));
$this->saveInvoices($response);


public function saveInvoices($invoices)
{
    foreach ($invoices as $item) {
        //If it wasn't paid and dueDate not passed, then save it to $this->filteredResults
        if(($item['paid'] === false) && ($item["dueDate"] <= $now)){
            $collection = collect($item);
            array_push($this->filteredResults, $collection->only(['invoiceNumber', 'customerId', 'customerName', 'dueDate', 'invoiceDate', 'amountInOriginalCurrency', 'paid'])->toArray());
        }

        //Then update invoice information, regardless of paid status
        UnpaidInvoices::updateOrCreate(
            ['invoiceNumber' => $item['invoiceNumber']],
            ['invoiceNumber' => $item['invoiceNumber'],
             'customerId' => $item['customerId'],
             'customerName' => $item['customerName'],
             'dueDate' => $item['dueDate'],
             'invoiceDate' => $item['invoiceDate'],
             'amountInOriginalCurrency' => $item['amountInOriginalCurrency'],
             'paid' => $item['paid']]);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's no an issue, those who are already saved In database needs to get updated,
e.g In DB a row is saved as paid: false, and the next API call the status of the paid is updated to true, then how I'm going to update it?

Comment: @SyedAmeerHamza my solution solve that. Look carefully at the code or try it yourself. It update all invoices received from API call, regardless it was paid=false or paid=true. Both cases will be updated.